# How to unhide the keyboard of the current active textbox?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, keyboard

I have an IBAction linked up to EditingDidBegin on all my UITextFields, so why isn't the following code working when the UITextFields are tapped on?

```
-(IBAction)keyboardShouldShow
{

[self becomeFirstResponder];

NSLog(@"Keyboard Showing");

}
```

Also bear in mind that the keyboard will not show unless this code is added because of other code I have in my project file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your self is not your textfield.try to change the method to this and relink it to editingdidbegin.

```
-(IBAction)keyboardShouldShow:(UITextField*)sender
{

[sender becomeFirstResponder];

NSLog(@"Keyboard Showing");

}
```

HIH

Comment: That error is because you have your Editing Did Begin event linked to keyboardShouldShow and not keyboardShouldShow: .Go back to interface builder, remove the redundant link and relink it to this method.

Comment: error has gone now but unfortunately the keyboard doesn't appear when the UITextField begins editing. Why is this?

Comment: Does it enter the method(check log)?Are you sure the user interaction with the textfield has been enabled?

Comment: it has, the NSLog statement appears when editing begins except the action itself ([sender becomeFirstResponder];) doesn't happen :(

Comment: oh, then sorry mate, i am stumped. I tested becomeFirstResponder and it brings the keyboard for me. Incidentally I tried to make it so that the keyboard does not appear(automatically) and failed. How did you manage that?

Comment: aww :( and  I did [textfield resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 0):

Because `self` is your view controller, not the `UITextField`.

Use the `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      NSLog(@"Keyboard Showing");
   }
}
```

And if you want to use your own method, be sure to pass the `UITextField` as a parameter.
Change the method to something like:

```
-(IBAction)keyboardShouldShow:(id)sender {
     if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
        NSLog(@"Keyboard Showing");
     }
```

}

Comment: so what can I put instead of "self"?

Comment: on the first bit of code, it doesn't recognise 'sender' - sorry to bother you but why is this?

Comment: Because you need to pass the parameter. Add the `(id):sender` means that interface builder will pass the control to the method when it's being called from interface builder. When you call that method your self you will need pass the parameter your self.

Comment: would you be able to give a small example please?